# Neglecting capacitor from circuit

Tags: electric-circuits, capacitance, voltage

Take a look at this circuit :

[image]

This question is answered in $Serway$ $7th$ ,And the book neglected 8 Farad capacitor because the voltage between $c$ and $d$ is zero.

My questions is :

$1.$Should not be $C$1 = $C$2 or $C$3 = $C$4 to get zero voltage between $c$ and $d$ ,Because these capacitors are different in capacitance so they will decrease the voltage in difference amount.

$2.$What happen to the current across $cd$ wire , Does it flow normally without charge 8 Farad capacitor or it doesn't flow because zero voltage.

$3.$Since there is a voltage between point $c$ and any point at capacitor which is zero , should not the current flow ?

Answer (score 2):

1. The fact that C1 and C2 have different values will ensure that the Charge induced in the capacitors will be different, not the Voltage drop.

To see this, forget about the $8\mu F$ Capacitor for a moment. The Voltage drop through the upper segment must be the same as the drop in the lower one, by Kirchoff's law. Also, by symmetry, the drop through C1 (let's call it $\Delta V_1$) must be the same as through C3 ($\Delta V_3$). Simmilarly, $\Delta V_2 = \Delta V_4$. Therefore,

$\Delta V_1 + \Delta V_3 = 2 \Delta V_1 = \Delta V_2 \Delta V_4 = 2\Delta V_2 \Rightarrow \Delta V_1 = \Delta V_2$.

We conclude that the voltage difference between C and D must be zero

2. Since the potential difference is zero, the induced charge is zero at every instant and no current flows between C and D.

Comment: Why the current doesn't flow through $cd$ wire , at point $c$ there is an electric potential and at point on 8 farad capacitor the electric potential if zero so there is a voltage so the current should flow ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know if I understand your question. Do you mean the potential is zero INSIDE the  8uF capacitor? If so, why?

Comment: Yes , Because the current has not flew yet. We reach a step that the current reach point $c$ ,Then there is a voltage between 8 farad capacitor and point $c$ because the current reach point $c$ but not 8 farad capacitor so ,So the current should flow through the $cd$ wire

Comment: You're right. There does seem to be a potential difference between C and the capacitor at the instant we connect the capacitor to the system or turn on the potential, if we consider the potential at the plates to be zero at this instant. But notice that this is also true for D. So there will be a small current inward or outward the capacitor, until the potentials are equalized. Because the current is inward/outward, the capacitor will not be charged, and after this current dissipates the potential will be constant through the CD wire, including 'inside the capacitor', and no current will flow.

Comment: Is there a connection between $C$3 and $C$4 through $cd$ wire ? I am asking because in similar question that need the equivalent capacitance in Serway , They neglected the 8 Farad capacitor but they didn't neglect the $cd$ wire.

Comment: What do you mean by connection? Does it ask for the total equivalent capacitance? If so, the way I'd go about it would be to first say that the equivalent capacitance between C1 and C3 would be 1/2 C1, and for C2 and C4, 1/2 C2. Then the total value would be 1/2 (C1 + C2), for paralel adding of capacitances. Do they do it differently? If so, could you tell me what question of Serway is that?